# I have data (Hour/Date) collect from the host pc and i can't put them in Text (Scene Builder)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Hello StackOverFlow comunity,

I have collect hour and date for a Java/JavaFX application project, i can take abd show them in the output with:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy\n  HH:mm");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
```

but when i want to use
    "name_of_my_text".setText(dtf.format(now));
to put it in my scene this doesn't work and show in the output too much JavaFX error.

Thanks for SOF comunity

Comment: Please show your stack trace, even if it is very long. It is very hard to help without it

Comment: I can't put it in comments how do u want i show it ?

Comment: Edit your question and put stack trace in there

Comment: yes, edit the question

Comment: There is a NullPointerException on line 84 of `VisioDiese`. Check this line for variables that have not been initialized properly.

Comment: Also, `System.out.println()` has an upper-case S, not lower-case. This may be the source of your problem, although unlikely.

Comment: Yes i know sorry it's with uppercase in my code, i think u don't understand my problem, i can show date and hour in my output but i want to use setText() to show it in my scene of scene builder

Comment: line 84 i have just this: `dateTime.setText(dtf.format(now));` who dateTime is the name of my Text in scene builder

Comment: @Sacha  are you able to print anything in Textfield, try to put some 3,4 character and try

Comment: I have try to change `dateTime.setText(dtf.format(now));` to `dateTime.setText("toto");` and this doesn't work too :/

Comment: same error trace

Comment: I have add code in the post for more simplicity

Comment: @Sacha  are you able to print anything on other Text component

Comment: @suneel nope, i have change like said up and this doesn't work too, i don't understand because i have do the same methode like line 71 and this work but not for the dateTime Text ...

Comment: @Sacha lets discuss here
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197922/test

Comment: I can't i need to have 20reputation and i'm new in stackoverflow :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, no screenshots but real text that can be copied and tested :)

Comment: i don't think we need a minimal repoductible example, it's work on line 71 and it's the same methode on line 85

Comment: Ok so i have resolve the problème ... he was between the chair and the keyboard

Comment: thks for helping me out